# Where to find AWS CLI documentation with updated values?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was working on creating AWS CLI scripts on operations that I've been manually doing earlier. I used AWS Cloudshell to easily execute the CLI commands. But when I check the autocomplete function of Cloudshell there are some extra commands and also some commands in the AWS CLI documentation that are currently not supported too.

I used this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html

Is there anywhere we get the details of those newly created arguments?

*An example is:
While creating aws ec2 key pair, some arguments like '--key-type' that is mentioned in the document is not supported.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AWS Cloudshell` runs on **Amazon Linux 2** and you have `root` access to it. So to update your aws cli version you do what you [would do on Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-upgrade):

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install --bin-dir /usr/local/bin --install-dir /usr/local/aws-cli --update
```

verify (newest is `2.2.30`)

```
aws --version
```

Also your AWS CLI link is for old verison v1. The docs for version v2 are [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/index.html).